# How to call the third slide in a slider from other pages

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, slider

Is it possible to directly call the third slide from a slider on this page:
http://casssh.com/ValueMyHome/SaB/form.html

```
 <ul class="navlist">
       <li><a id="testSlide1" class="navlink" href="index.html">Value My Home</a></li>
       <li><a id="testSlide2" class="navlink" href="index.html">Rent My Home</a></li>
       <li><a id="testSlide3" class="navlink" href="index.html">Property Market Analysis</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html" class="navlink">About Us</a></li>
   </ul><br>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    var $slider = $('#da-slider');
    // initialize the slider
    $slider.cslider();
    // example how to go to page 1 when clicking on a link
    $('#testSlide1').on( 'click', function( event ) {
        $('index.html').('#da-slider').cslider( 'page', 0 );
                return false;
        });
});
```

I do this from index page, but I can't from form.html and other pages.